# How to put content of text file into the variable?

Tags: bash

I know there are similar questions and i first searched for the answer there,but couldn't make bit of code work.

The idea is-user inputs the name of the folder ,than the name of the file in this folder and program should put content of file  to variable.

```
echo " Type name of the folder where you want to edit file "
read folder
echo " Type name of the file you want to edit "
read file
#cont=$(cat "$folder"/"$file")
#cont=$(cat test/test1.txt)//its the name of existing variable and file so should work
cont=`cat test/test1.txt`
echo "$cont"
```

I tried different solutions but they only work for files in current directory.
Maybe someone has any ideas of the right syntax,or possible solution.
Thanks in advance!

after i tried cont=cat "$folder"/"$file" i was written test/test1.txt: Text file busy.The problem isnt in file or folder variable or path that was provided,it just doesnt pass value to variable it this way

Comment: `cat "$folder"/"$file"` should have worked. Of course, `$folder` will be interpreted relative to the current directory, unless it's an absolute path.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Your code is not limited to the current directory, it will work for files in any directory the user specifies.

Comment: Yes it should work for any files in any directory but it doesn't,it worked if I didn't use variables just typing file name in current directory.
However it doesnt work when I write name of the directory and a file,like in example.So i concluded that problem is not in variables.

Comment: You're saying that if the user enters `test` and `test1.txt` it doesn't work the same as what wrote?

Comment: exactly, and i cant really find a mistake

Comment: Works fine for me. There's something you're not showing us.

Comment: What if you just write `cat "$folder"/"$file"` without assigning to a variable?

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `echo $(cat...)`. This is Useless use of `echo`. Just `cat` works.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo " Type name of the folder where you want to edit file "
read folder
echo " Type name of the file you want to edit "
read file
var=$(cat "$folder"/"$file")
echo "$var"
```

Result :

```
$] ./test.sh
Type name of the folder where you want to edit file 
test1
Type name of the file you want to edit 
table
cat
dog
```

This also works if executed from another directory while giving the full path of the input folder.

```
$] ./path/to/test.sh
Type name of the folder where you want to edit file 
/path/to/folder
Type name of the file you want to edit
table
cat
dog
```

Comment: The question says _put contents of the file into a variable_. I think the `echo` was just demo code.

Comment: The downvote is absurd. Putting the content of a `cat` to a var an echoing is just useless. Can I know why the downvote ?

Comment: The echo is just debugging code to see if the variable's contents are correct. It's obviously not his ultimate goal.

Comment: @Barmar How do you know ? Did you assume it !?

Comment: Yes, I assumed it, based on the title and text of the question. Anyway, the problem he described is with getting files in some other directory, so whether he uses cat or an assignment is irrelevant.

Comment: He says that all his solutions _only work for files in current directory_. How does changing from an assignment to `cat` solve that problem?

Comment: I'm sorry for confusion-echo is really there just for debugging

Comment: @user2195672 : Fine. I have edited my answer. `echo` works from both local and remote directories for me this way.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have a shell environment problem (your first attempt with `cont=$(cat "$folder"/"$file")` should works), try to use another env :

```
exec bash
```

then

```
read -p "Type name of the folder where you want to edit file >>> " dir
read -p " Type name of the file you want to edit >>> " file

cont="$(< "$dir/$file")"

echo "$cont"
```

Tested OK with `/etc/passwd`

Comment: How will this fix whatever problem he's having in his original code? It's just a different way to do the same thing.

Comment: The syntax is better and *it works*. backticks should be avoided, `$( )` way is better. The OP example with the first comment decommented works for me

Comment: Will it solve the problem that it _only work for files in current directory_? The problem he's having isn't with his assignment syntax, it has something to do with letting the user specify the directory. It's not clear what he's really expecting.

Comment: Added explanations about env suspected problem